# Get short days of week in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, get

How i get days of week (SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY etc.) as short format(SUN,MON,TUE etc.) for system locale in Android?

```
String mondayshort --> output:"MON"(for English) or "LUN"(for French)
String tuesdatshort --> output:"TUE"(for English) or "MAR"(for French)
String wednesdayshort --> output:"WED"(for English) or "MER"(for French)
```

Comment: Have you tried just using `SimpleDateFormat` and `MMM` as the format pattern?

Comment: can you write an example?

Comment: There are *lots* of examples of SimpleDateFormat on Stack Overflow, and in the documentation, and in numerous other pages on the web. I suggest you try it yourself first, and if you have problems you edit what you've tried (along with the expected result and the actual result) into the question.

Comment: @Joe i dont want current day. i want days of week for system locale

Comment: @JonSkeet: With all my respects... but isn't `MMM` used for formatting **months**? I guess the OP needs `EEE`, instead. Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @DerGolem: Yes, you're absolutely right - EEE is whats called for. Was too hasty.

Comment: @Taha: once you know how to do today's date, it's trivial to work put how to do another date. It's important to be learn to adapt code which does *some* of what you want.

Comment: @JonSkeet... **EPIC WIN**!! I corrected **JonSkeet**!!!! ;)

Comment: i dont want current day of week. i want get short character for days of week

Comment: Then simply add the **locale** in your SimpleDateFormat constructor: `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);` Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @Taha: repeating your previous comment doesn't in any way address my response to it.

Comment: my string is "monday" "sunday" and i get short monday for system locale in "monday". i get short sunday for system locale in "sunday" can i get this strings?

Comment: What do you mean by "my string is"? What string? It's not at all clear what you're trying to do now. I've added an answer for what I *thought* you wanted, but that doesn't naturally have a string input...

Comment: example:String monday ----- in output, MON or LUN

Comment: It's still not clear whether you mean you've got a user *input* of "monday", or whether you're just declaring a string *variable* called monday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To format a specific date (not necessarily the current date), use `EEE` in a `SimpleDateFormat`. If you want *all* the short days of the week, you could use

```
DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols(locale);
String[] shortDays = symbols.getShortWeekdays();
```

Comment: @Tahakörkem: Well then access the right element of the array. That method gives you an array with all of them, so you can then get the ones you want.

Comment: @Joe Skeet this code is works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Write EEEE for your requirement. If you need complete code tell me I will show you. :)

Comment: That will give long format - the OP needs EEE for short format.

Comment: Yes you people are right, I thought he ask for full day name so I post that. EEE returns short form.